# asp.net mvc 3 silverlight like validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

**MAIN QUESTION**

As the title says, i'm asking if anyone knows how to create a validation structure similar to silverlight's dataform. Any hints, materials , ideas would be welcome. I'd like to do a validation like this:

[image]

(You can check this out [here](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html))

**DETAILS**

I've been trying to something like the example above, but without results until now. Mostly because i dont' know how the validation message helper works. I've managed to a single validation message by taking the data-val-number attribute and set it into a link title (using a third party jquery plugin callled qTip to show a tooltip error message). However, i can't do the same thing if there are more than one validation.

So, is it possible to rewrite the validation message helper? I'd like to understand more how it shows the validation messages so i can put them on any html content. This would do the tooltip part and i could set as many messages as i want, with any formatting i desire.

And i'd like to be able to show the validation messages through any jquery events (mouseover, click, dblclick, ready, etc.). As far as i understand on it's actual implementation, the validation only occurs when the user changes focus from the actual input to another html element.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you checkout the validation rules section in [Professional ASP.NET MVC](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf). It shows how to do exactly what you describe with ASP.NET MVC v1 and it works all the way up through v3.

The displayed user interface is slightly different; however, you can check the output and write your own CSS to make it look just like your screenshot.

For a quick example:

**Action Result**

```
try 
{
    // code
}
catch
{
    foreach (var issue in std.GetRuleViolations())
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(issue.PropertyName, issue.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Phone) && !Utility.IsValidPhoneNumber(this.Phone))
    {
        yield return new RuleViolation("Phone is invalid. Try this format: ###-###-####.", "HomePhone");
    }  

    yield break;         
}
```

**Edit View**

```
<% 
    using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
%>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Edit</legend>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Create was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Phone", Model.Phone)%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Phone", "*")%>
    <!-- more fields go here -->
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

**rule violation class -- lifted from link**

```
public class RuleViolation
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

    public RuleViolation(string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public RuleViolation(string errorMessage, string propertyName)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

Comment: if i understood correclty, i'd have to create every validation for each property i want to validate. My problem is how i present those validations errors the way i want, cause i don't know how the js scripts fires the validation event. I saw that you don't use any data annotations attributes. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: Its copied directly from the book, which is for MVC1. There may be a more elegent way to do it in MVC3, I just don't know it.

Comment: yes, there it is. As i said, i'm not concerned on how the mvc framework creates a validation, just how it shows it to the user, through which jquery events, methods, etc.